# IIS Redirect requests from domain to other domain

Tags: redirect, iis, model-view-controller

I have a MVC website published on IIS and its domain name is for example **[www.example.com.sa](http://www.example.com.sa)** and I need to redirect any requests to **[www.example.sa](http://www.example.sa)**
also if any user request any url like the following:

- **[www.example.com.sa](http://www.example.com.sa)** to be redirect to **[www.example.sa](http://www.example.sa)**
- **[www.example.com.sa/index](http://www.example.com.sa/index)** to be redirect **to [www.example.sa/index](http://www.example.sa/index)**
- **[www.example.com.sa/index/create](http://www.example.com.sa/index/create)** to be redirect to **[www.example.sa/index/create](http://www.example.sa/index/create)**

Answer (score 0):

This rule can judge `www.example.com.sa` and redirect it.

```
<rule name="redirect rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com.sa" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.sa/{R:0}" />
 </rule>
```